# why do people create a standard for programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, standards, specifications

why do people create a standard(or specification) for every language soon after its developed?

**C++**

> In 1998, the C++ standards committee (the ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21
>   working group) standardized C++ and published the international
>   standard ISO/IEC 14882:1998 (informally known as C++98).

**Java**

> In 1997, Sun Microsystems approached the ISO/IEC JTC1 standards body
>   and later the Ecma International to formalize Java, but it soon
>   withdrew from the process.

**JavaScript**

> In November 1996, Netscape announced that it had submitted JavaScript
>   to Ecma International for consideration as an industry standard, and
>   subsequent work resulted in the standardized version named ECMAScript.

and the list goes on.

Comment: Why do people create standards for screws?

Comment: Perosnally, I hate performing an action and knowing the result will be the same every time.

Comment: Although this is semi-off-topic, I do think that Jerry Coffin's and JaredMcAteer's answers are pretty close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily to assure that different implementations agree on what actually constitutes the language, and therefore what they accept and reject in programs written in that language.

This is largely driven by the fact that early on, many languages (e.g., Lisp) were *not* standardized, which led to fragmentation and incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Standards are developed so that companies and individuals that want to implement or build compilers or use the languages, know what the expected behaviors are of language and ensure they are consistent across implementations.

Comment: Thanks you for answering. I'm not sure why this question was marked non constructive. I would be running around digging for this knowledge still if it were asked and answered here.

Comment: It's not that it's not constructive, it's just not a fit for the spirit of this stackoverflow. I don't think the option existed in 2012 but I would have voted to move this question to a more appropriate site like programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JaredMcAteer this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Where does it fit then? lol. Thanks for at least explaining your reasons though, that puts my mind at ease hehe

Answer (score 1):

For the simple fact that (as happened with Java) each company will each go off in a different direction with the language. Standards create a minimum specification for the language that all compilers following the standard should adhere to.